# How to increment a counter with upper limit in Django models, with a single query?

Tags: python, django, multithreading, django-models

I have a Django model like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    upper_limit = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    counter = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

The counter of a record needs to be incremented frequently:

```
 mymodel = MyModel.objects.get(pk=123)
 mymodel.counter = F('counter') + 1
 mymodel.save()
```

The thing is: I need to make sure mymodel.counter is less than mymodel.upper_limit before making the update. I can make a query before updating:

```
if mymodel.counter < mymodel.upper_limit:
    mymodel.counter = F('counter') + 1
    mymodel.save()
```

But there are problems with this approach: The counter may not be accurate. Other threads may have updated the counter in database after my query, and the counter will exceed the limit when I increment it. I know I can use `select_for_update()` to lock the row, but I don't want to do that, because that way all increment actions will be serialized, blocking the threads.

What I want is to only update the counter when it is less than upper_limit, in a single query like this:

```
UPDATE MyModel set counter = counter + 1 
where id=123 and counter<upper_limit
```

Is this doable with Django ORM?

*I have been thinking about pre_save signal, but the signal handler needs to know about the upper_limit, so that is a dead-end.*

UPDATE:
How about this, will this generate one SQL?

```
updated_rows = MyModel.objects.filter(pk=123,   
   counter__lt=F("upper_limit")).update(counter=F("counter")+1)
# if updated_rows > 0, I know the counter is incremented
```

I am not sure if the statement above will get me the single query, because update method returns a int, not a queryset, so I cannot print its `query`.

Comment: yes, I think your query in the updated question will do it :)

Comment: you can check the generated sql by: `from django.db import connection; # do your query; print connection.queries`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need consistency at DB level, so neither of app-side methods will ensure that. What you need is logic inside database. You can achieve that with triggers or with [conditional updates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-update) in Django >= 1.8.

Comment: Trigger is a good idea. But does Django ORM support defining triggers?

Comment: @neowang I don't know such. Probably you'll need some 3rd-party solution, as controlling database-specific procedures should be out of ORM scope